# Getting date value of current chosen month till previous months

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am stuck at a dax problem.
I have two tables i.e Date table and File closure table( this table is having file closure month that is having a relationship with date table month). now i am using month name from date table into my slicer and want to count the number of row in file closure table from chosen month till the start of the year.

E.g. say i chosed march from slicer than the number of rows i want to count from file cosure table should be from january till march.
I cannot chose multiple months to add previous  month data due to my schema limitations.

Kindly help me out in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In business intelligence we call this Year-to-date analysis.

This can be done by using time intelligence functions which require the date table to be marked as date table.

Use one of these functions: TOTALYTD or DATESYTD.

The following formula creates a measure that calculates the 'Year to date' for Internet sales.

```
= TOTALYTD(SUM(InternetSales_USD[SalesAmount_USD]),DateTime[DateKey])
```

Visit : https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/bi/creating-time-intelligence-functions-in-dax/